# order of calling pthread_cond_signal and change condition variable

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, condition-variable

I know that pthread_cond_signal/pthread_cond_broadcast should be called after changing the condition variable to indicate a condition change, but if they both happen with lock held, does the order matter? For example

1. pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
2. pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
3. condition = true
4. pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

the waiter's wakeup must happen after step 4(to retrieve the mutex), so the waiter must have seen the update condition variaable

Comment: What is a condition variable? Could you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @273K I have updated my question. This is not a reproducible executable code, just to study the theory behind.

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. Please select one language. And in C++ (11 and onwards) it is recommended to use the standard `std::condition_variable`, `std::mutex` etc.

Comment: Is there any reason you still use pthreads?  As mentioned C++ has the condition variable and mutex build in, and also `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` which will avoid problems by making it impossible to foget to unlock mutexes in case of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right.
If the code checking this condition is written in a correct way, this should not be a problem.

e.g.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while(!state)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Comment: However, it is not necessary to hold the associated mutex locked when you signal or broadcast to a CV.  Waiting to do so until after releasing the mutex can provide a small efficiency boost to a waiting thread.